# How to Disable and Drop all Temporal Tables from a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm working on a task where I need to backup and restore a database in another instance.

But, when I restore that database, I need to Drop all the History Tables associated with Temporal Tables.

Is there a quick way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that's what you need.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON ;
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR (MAX);

DECLARE
    @SchemaName VARCHAR(100),
    @TableName VARCHAR(100),
    @HistorySchemaName VARCHAR(100),
    @HistoryTableName VARCHAR(100);

SET @cmd = '' ;

SELECT TOP ( 1 )
       @SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(T1.schema_id ),
       @TableName = T1 .name,
       @HistorySchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(T2.schema_id ),
       @HistoryTableName = T2 .name
FROM sys .tables T1
LEFT JOIN sys .tables T2
    ON T1.history_table_id = T2 .object_id
WHERE T1. temporal_type = 2
ORDER BY T1. name;


WHILE @@ROWCOUNT = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME (@SchemaName ) + '. ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF );
DROP TABLE '       + QUOTENAME (@HistorySchemaName ) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@HistoryTableName );
        EXEC sp_executesql @cmd

        SELECT TOP ( 1 )
               @SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(T1.schema_id ),
               @TableName = T1 .name,
               @HistorySchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(T2.schema_id ),
               @HistoryTableName = T2 .name
        FROM sys.tables T1
        LEFT JOIN sys.tables T2
            ON T1 .history_table_id = T2 .object_id
        WHERE
            T1 .temporal_type = 2
            AND T1 .name > @TableName
        ORDER BY T1 .name;
    END;
```

Comment: Probably one of the fastest answers I've ever come across!  You obviously must have had this script in your back pocket.  Maybe worth providing some context just for others as they come across it.

Comment: @bege1, did that worked for you?

Comment: @John, yes indeed! I do have this script but wrapped inside of a stored procedure where I used to need to remove history data when moving database around in a environment with multi-tenant databases.

Comment: This is working perfectly!!!!! Thanks for sharing @Dan